# Get the number of Opportunities for each User in the org (the count must include the records to which the User has atleast read access)

Tags: scheduled-apex, permissions, dynamic-soql, userrecordaccess

I need to get the count of Opportunity record for every User in the org where the User has atleast read access on the Opportunity record. I need to store the data obtained per User for every month in a custom object .

Comment: schedulable class on Opportunity Share, UserRecordAccess object
Reporting snapshot

Comment: What is your sharing model? OWD Private? Apex Sharing? Sharing Rules? Role Hierarchy?

Comment: OWD is private for Opportunity. Yes, we are using Apex managed Sharing and Sharing setting to share Opportunities with Users in our org. Even Team is also being used.

Comment: What didn't work about exporting the `OpportunityShare`/`UserRecordAccess` records? Those seem like viable strategies. Also why does it need to be  a custom object? Is an export of existing data sufficient?

Comment: I need to actually show a bar graph of opp count vs the current month for every User(who has logged in). This graph must include previous month data also. So i need to store it in a custom object or else i wont get the past data.

Comment: If a user has view All permission(Sys Admin,Sales Admin etc.), exporting on Opportunity Share won't give me the exact count for these Users. Opportunity Share won't include the records which are accessible to Users via profile or permission sets.